# Using Quickfield LabelMover to extract specific local values at coordinates

Tags: voltage, simulation, matlab, field-strength

Quickfield Student Edition

I've attempted using Quickfield's LabelMover Serial Analysis to automatically get local values of interest at a set of different specific coordinates, but I couldn't find a way to extract values from specific coordinates.

The help section doesn't specify my problem, I did however find that viewing the "Contour" shows me multiple points.

I'm not sure if this is the right Stack to ask about app usage, I feel like it's relevant.

Comment: It's not clear to me if this is an electrical engineering software tool, but assuming that it is, it would probably be on topic. But you would not necessarily have the best time getting answers, even if the question is legal. I would recommend support through matlab forums.

Comment: @craisc It's not limited to matlab, Quickfield API can be used by any programming environment, LabelMover happens to be the way for non-programmers to use automation in QuickField problem solving. It is infact an electrical engineering tool, in layman terms, it simulates electrical fields and the influence it has on different mediums.

Comment: Of course, I only have the layman's knowledge about this application which is why I'm asking in the first place. :)

Comment: I see. Ok, I think My comment still applies. To me it is generally on topic , but your chances of getting a good answer is unpredictable.

Comment: I've used QF label mover years ago to do what you appear to be asking so, it's definitely doable.

Comment: @Andyaka for a moment I was ready to write an auto clicking auto typing program to copy and paste Local Values from the Field Picture into another open text file.             If you can remember how you exactly you did that it would be so great.

Comment: 15 years ago, sorry.